# Do we need @InOnly annotation or <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"/> if we are using sendBody method of ProducerTemplate?

Tags: apache-camel

For POJO producing, it is mentioned in Camel docs that InOut is the default.
But, if we are using the sendBody() of ProducerTemplate, is there any need of setting @InOnly also as in the example below.

```
public class MyBean {

@Produce(uri = "direct:hello")
private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

@InOnly
void someInOnlyMethod()
{
...
producerTemplate.sendBody("mystr");
...
}
}
```

Similarly in the example below, if direct:hello gets a message from the above MyBean object configured without the @InOnly annotation, do we need the setExchangePattern element?

```
 <route>
 <from uri="direct:hello"/>
 <setExchangePattern pattern="InOnly"/>
 <to uri="mock:result"/>      
 </route>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
No when you use the producer template then the MEP is set accordingly to the method you use on the template. eg all send methods is InOnly, and all request methods is InOut. Though some methods has a pattern parameter where you can specify the MEP.

2)
No you often dont have to set/change the MEP. Though in situations where you send a message to a endpoint which supports both InOnly or InOut (and behaves differently) you may want to set the MEP explicit to your needs.

See about these EIPs for details

- http://camel.apache.org/event-message.html
- http://camel.apache.org/request-reply.html

for example a JMS endpoint can do InOnly (send only to a queue) or InOut (do request/reply over JMS) etc.